# Hide a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div. I'm successful in hiding it. But, I think it's not the right way. I'm trying to hide the whole div which internally has lot of DOM elements like span & div.. Here is my code. I think I should not show or hide by using number of times of parent().. What could be the short or quicker one? Any thoughts?

```
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

My HTML code is

```
                    <div class="col-md-12 ncbclaim-slider raja">

                        <div tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement." showtooltipon="hover" class="claim-details-tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio checked">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" class="validate basic-required-options" data-toggle="radio"  id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">0%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(1 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div title="" data-original-title="" class="claim-details-tooltip" showtooltipon="hover" tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement.">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim" id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes"  data-toggle="radio" class="validate basic-required-options">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">20%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(2 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div title="" data-original-title="" class="claim-details-tooltip" showtooltipon="hover" tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement.">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim" id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes"  data-toggle="radio" class="validate basic-required-options">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">25%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(3 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div title="" data-original-title="" class="claim-details-tooltip" showtooltipon="hover" tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement.">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim" id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes"  data-toggle="radio" class="validate basic-required-options">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">35%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(4 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div title="" data-original-title="" class="claim-details-tooltip" showtooltipon="hover" tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement.">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim" id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes"  data-toggle="radio" class="validate basic-required-options">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">45%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(5 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div tooltip-message="If you have claimed before, then select 'Yes'. An NCB (No Claim Bonus) certificate will be required from your previous insurer at the time of claim settlement." showtooltipon="hover" class="claim-details-tooltip" data-original-title="" title="">
                            <div class="touch-icon">
                                <label class="radio">
                                    <label for="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes&quot;&quot;">
                                        <div class="radio-box">
                                            <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-radio-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-radio-checked"></span></span><input type="radio" class="validate basic-required-options" data-toggle="radio"  id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimInLastPolicyPeriodYes" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim">
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="city-name">50%</span>
                                        <span class="city-name">(&gt;5 yrs)</span>
                                    </label>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: what is the class/id of the div you want to show/hide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();claim-details-tooltip
```

Change your original code like this below ↓↓↓↓↓

```
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').parents('.claim-details-tooltip').show();
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parents('.claim-details-tooltip').hide();
```

please use `.parents()` API next time when you try to do something like this. It will go up to the specified selector, so you don't have to use `.parent()` over and over again.

Comment: Thanks Hina. It will display all buttons at once. Not correct in this case.

Comment: @ShaikNizamAli What do you mean by 'Not correct in this case'? Aren't you looking for an easy way to find some specific ancestors?  If there's more, please update your question. I'm looking into it then.

Comment: I was doing do hide and display only specific radio buttons along with div. But, with the updated code of you, it displays all at once without any validation.

Comment: @ShaikNizamAli You didn't even mention a single word about the button work in your question, so I didn't care about it. Anyway, problem has been solved, right?

Comment: No, It's still the same issue. Have you updated the code? I see its still the same code, right?

Comment: @ShaikNizamAli Alright, could you please just tell me what do you want me to do further on your code here [jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/40.](http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/40.) Do you still want to avoid the `parent()` chain there?

Comment: I just want to hide and remove radio buttons based on year selected. I should not use long chain of parent().parent().

Comment: Please check this fiddle and update it http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/41/ .. Thanks Hina

Comment: @ShaikNizamAli I still don't know exactly what do you want. Be specific like " when I select 2014, I want to show two radio buttons " and update your question with the details. Long line of comments like this doesn't look good. Please update your question with 'details about what do you want to do, specifically'

Comment: It's working fine. The fiddle is the right one. Just play it by changing the year. 2014->only first radio button, 2013->two radio buttons, and so on.. I just don't want to write more parent().parent().... That's the only issue Hina.

Comment: @ShaikNizamAli http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/42/ check out here. I've just updated your jsFiddle

Comment: Awesome. I don't understand why it's not working in the project. I need to take a look again. Thanks Hina

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You can use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) selector.

```
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').parents(".claim-details-tooltip").show();
$('.raja input:radio[name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS.noClaim"]').not(':lt('+(noNcbYear + 1)+')').parents(".claim-details-tooltip").hide();
```

Comment: It will display all buttons at once.